# Coercing Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<MyStruct>>>>> to Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<dyn Trait>>>>> won't work

Tags: rust

I'm trying to store a dyn trait inside `Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<>>>>>`, however for some reason it won't work

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

trait A{}

struct B{}

impl A for B{}

struct H{
    c: Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<dyn A>>>>
}

fn main() {
    let c = 
    Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some(Box::new(B{}))));
    H{
        c: c
    };
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:17:12
   |
17 |         c: c
   |            ^ expected trait object `dyn A`, found struct `B`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<(dyn A + 'static)>>>>`
              found struct `Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<B>>>>`
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=93208381e1f69ac5ae716a13c1ad803f)</sup>

It looks like it cannot store a `dyn` as a `Box<B>`, which is strange because this works:

```
fn main() {
    let c: Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<dyn A>>>> = 
    Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some(Box::new(B{}))));
}
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the difference?

There is a very special case for `Box` and other standard library types that can contain dynamically-sized values like `dyn A`.

```rust
let c = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some(Box::new(B{}))));
H { c: c };
```

In this code, you have initialized the variable `c` — with no type declaration — to a value whose type is inferred as `Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<B>>>`, and then try to store it in a field of of type `Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<dyn A>>>`. This cannot work, because the two types have different memory layouts.

```rust
let c: Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<dyn A>>>> = 
    Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some(Box::new(B{}))));
```

In this code, you *have* given `c` a type declaration, as a consequence of which the need for `dyn` is known *at the point where it is constructed,* which allows the coercion to happen soon enough, You can coerce a `Box<B>` to a `Box<dyn A>`, because `Box` implements the special trait [`CoerceUnsized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html). (The same mechanism applies to converting `&B` to `&dyn A`.) But, this does not apply to arbitrary types *containing* a `Box<B>` — not even `Option<Box<B>>`, let alone your more complex type.

You can give `c` a type when you're constructing it:

```rust
let c: Arc<Mutex<Option<Box<dyn A>>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some(Box::new(B{}))));
H { c: c };
```

Or, slightly shorter but odder, you can annotate just the immediate container of the `Box` with the type it needs:

```rust
let c = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some::<Box<dyn A>>(Box::new(B{}))));
H { c: c };
```

Or you can write an explicit coercion with the `as` operator:

```rust
let c = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some(Box::new(B{}) as Box<dyn A>)));
H { c: c };
```